# How can I do cv2 operations along side deep learning model on gpu?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

cv2 is using CPU while performing inference on deep learning model I want to do inference using gpu for deep learning models is there any way? I tried to do cv2.UMat() but it only supported when I am not using deep learning when I started using deep learning it hasn't worked. Please let me know how can we do cv2 operations and deep learning at the time.

Comment: What do you mean "it hasn't worked"? What exactly did you try, what did expect to see and what did you see?

Comment: I implemented the object detection inference using GPU and I am converting to cv2.UMat for reading the image later I need to convert it back to NumPy array as I want to expand dimensions when does this the fps reduced rather increasing

Comment: The ultimate goal is to increase the FPS

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow/Keras (with tensorflow backend) reserves whole gpu memory, even if they only need part of it. You'll have to check the docs if it's possible to reserve only part of it.

Comment: I will be allocating memory for keras and I will try to do that. I tried it before I haven't seen any significant improvement